# Drag formula and copy across columns across workbooks

Tags: google-sheets

Im trying to link data between 2 different workbooks (Google spreadsheets) using the formula below.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1y0y_9vlQlKdLfvZ0trrEacMzv_nxT4Jr50Z3L8aN", "Overview Weekly!m23")
```

As I copy this formula to the next row, I would like the formula to update to the next column. i.e

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1y0y_9vlQlKdLfvZ0trrEacMzv_nxT4Jr50Z3L8aN", "Overview Weekly!n23")
```

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `address` command, sequencing the columns as you fill down the rows.

```
=importrange("1zm67OStnh6UkHQgahQJzrMiy-umXQ1DRycf2wg-KUrs", address(23, row(13:13), 1, 1, "Overview Weekly"))
```

The `address` function will construct the string representation of a cell reference that you need for the `importrange` function.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed.